# Shut off valves to tankless hot water heater won't turn

Tags: water

I'm trying to descale my tankless hot water heater but have run into an issue. When I go to turn the water off, both valves will not turn at all. They have two yellow handles (looks like Apollo brand) and I can't get them to budge. Is there some trick to these valves? Or is this just a sign that the previous owners haven't done this in a while and it's possible both valves are stuck (sigh...)...

Comment: [Standard ball valve](https://www.amronintl.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/p/apollo-valves-series-ball-valve-70-101-10---70-web-1.jpg)? Probably just stuck. Look closely at the swing stop and make sure you're pushing the right way.

Comment: My tankless isolation/ flush valves are closed by an aprox 90 deg CCW turn (as seen from the handle side). If you verify the correct direction on yours, you could use a wrench on the handle.

Answer (score 2):

Post a picture of the valves to clarify, but in my opinion those valves are blocked by limestone, so you have to replace them.